# Uniform continuity question

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

Undoubtedly quite simple, but I'm stuck:

If $f$: $[a, b)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, must $\lim\limits_{x\longrightarrow b}f(x)$ exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. By definition of uniformly continuous, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any $x,y\in(b-\delta,b)$, it is always true that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.
By Cauchy criterion, this means that $\lim\limits_{x\to b}f(x)$ exist.

Comment: Cauchy criterion for function limits... after all these years playing around with elementary analysis one always learns something new.